# Django and Celery tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

So in our Django project we're using Celery and the Django-Celery module. The person that originally wrote the tasks section wrote it like so:

```
from djcelery import celery

@celery.task
def do_something():
    ...
```

But everywhere in the docs it shows that we should create a separate celery.py file and import the app like so:

celery.py

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('project')
if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

tasks.py

```
from celery import app # Importing `app` from our celery.py

@app.task
def do_something():
    ...
```

So I'm wondering if there's a problem doing it one way or the other? We're using django-celery version 3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First page in [start with celery documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

> Previous versions of Celery required a separate library to work
>   with Django, but since 3.1 this is no longer the case. Django is
>   supported out of the box now so this document only contains a basic
>   way to integrate Celery and Django. You’ll use the same API as
>   non-Django users so you’re recommended to read the First Steps with
>   Celery tutorial first and come back to this tutorial. When you have a
>   working example you can continue to the Next Steps guide.

Also first line of readme for django-celery states following

> Old django celery integration project.

To summarize following, django-celery is old approach used by your app and new documentation follows new way of handling celery

Comment: Thanks. I read that paragraph, but I didn't understand that it was referring to the django-celery library.

Comment: That means that you don't need django-celery library, you can integrate celery with django directly, you can read about celery and first steps here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#first-steps

Answer (score 1):

Both approaches you mentioned are valid ways to define tasks in a Django project using Celery. The difference lies in how you structure your code and configure Celery.

In the first approach you mentioned, the tasks are defined directly within the Django project's codebase using the `@celery.task` decorator from `djcelery`. This approach works well and is suitable for smaller projects or projects where you prefer to keep the task definitions within the same module as the rest of your Django code.

In the second approach, you create a separate `celery.py` file, which is a recommended practice for larger projects or projects where you want to decouple the task definitions from the main Django code. By using a separate file, you can configure Celery and its settings independently from the rest of the Django project. This approach provides more flexibility, especially if you have complex Celery configurations or want to separate concerns.

The second approach allows you to configure the Celery app using the `Celery` class from the `celery` module, whereas the first approach uses the `celery` object provided by `djcelery`. The `Celery` class from the `celery` module provides more configuration options and flexibility compared to the `celery` object from `djcelery`.

If you are using Django-Celery version 3.1, it is likely an older version that may have different conventions or recommendations compared to the latest versions. However, both approaches you mentioned should still work in version 3.1.

In general, if you are starting a new project or have the flexibility to make changes, I would recommend following the second approach with a separate `celery.py` file(should create in the same folder contains settings.py). It provides a cleaner separation of concerns and allows for more extensive Celery configuration options.
In celery.py,

```
import os

from celery import Celery

# Set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj')
# In the above instead of proj use your project name


# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django apps.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True, ignore_result=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

In init.py in the same folder, copy paste the below code ,

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

In settings.py,

```
# Celery Configuration
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'  # URL of your message broker (e.g., Redis) Replace with your Redis connection details
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'  # Result backend using Django database
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache'  # Cache backend using Django cache

# Celery Results Configuration (Optional)
CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES = 3600  # Result expiration time (in seconds)
```

In settings.py,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
...
    'django_celery_results',
    'django_celery_beat',


    ....
]
```

write the below code in command prompt to run celery,

```
celery -A project_name worker --loglevel=info
```

Refer https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify issues.